# How to edit part of string value in an array in PHP and use it in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, parsing

I am a novice, and I am trying to learn. 
First of all, on my Javascript code in the same file, it does NOT recognize a path when specified as `c:/wamp/www`. I need to use `/videolibrary/` instead (which is configured in `httpd.conf`).
Now, I need to pass a list of files from PHP which sees it as `C:/wamp/www...` and does not understand `/videolibrary/`. This is the code I have;

```
$videolibrary = "C:/wamp/www";
$filelist = array();
$filelist = glob("$videolibrary/$usr/*.webm");
$arrlength = count($filelist);
foreach ($filelist as $file)
{
    echo $file;
}
```

Now, how, do I use this `$filelist` on Javascript wherein its values are like `{/videolibrary/1.jpg, /videolibrary/2.jpg....}` instead of `{c:/wamp/www/1.jpg, c:/wamp/www/2.jpg....}`. Please help. On the JS side;

```
fl1 = <?php echo json_encode($filelist);?>;
for (i=1; i < sources.length; i++) {
      sources[i]=fl1[i-1]; //however this has c:/wamp/www and NOT /videolibrary
      var srcName=sources[i];
      }
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Why use the `$file` instead of `$filelist` like `echo '/videolibrary/'.$file`? Maybe I am missing something...

Comment: As Rasclatt says, does the `$file` variable in your foreach not return the filename?

Comment: I want to pass the array directly so I can use the array to loop through files, - how would I do this if I passed every file? I solved it below, please see if it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I posted the question, a wave of enthusiasm took over me and I solved this myself. 
I did this;

```
foreach ($filelist as $file)
{
    $file1=str_replace($search,$replace,$file);
    $filelist1[]=$file1;
}
foreach ($filelist1 as $file1){
    echo $file1;
}
```

Now, I could pass the modified $filelist1 as the array to Javascript. Yes. Here search is the string to search and replace is the string to replace (/videolibrary/).

Comment: you can use `basename($file)` instead of `str_replace`. :)

Comment: Can u please explain? I checked the basename function and it's defined as "Given a string containing the path to a file or directory, this function will return the trailing name component.". How can I use this for my case?

Comment: You might find it a cleaner alternative to return an array of just the filenames (which can easily be done using the basename function), and add the path (assuming it's fixed) late on in your javascript.